# How do I increment the score by 10 when a user collects a coin in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Right now its going up by 1 but I need it to go up by 10 whenever a coin is collected. How do I do that? I tried doing it this way self.score + 10 
but that didn't work. Thanks! If you need more code or info let me know!!

```
  if firstBody.categoryBitMask == HeroCategory && sixthBody.categoryBitMask == CoinCategory {
        sixthBody.node!.removeFromParent()

        self.score++
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To increment a value by 10, use:

```
self.score += 10
```

See the documentation for [Compound Assignment Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID69) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way (and most syntactically acceptable for Swift) to do that would be this:

```
self.score += 10
```

But another method (that is simply a longer way of writing the above code) is this:

```
self.score = self.score + 10
```

You can read all about compound assignment operators [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID69) in Apple's documentation for Swift.

Answer (score 2):

When increasing a value, there are a couple ways to do this. In your case, you need to increase a value by 10.

Heres one way:

```
self.score = self.score + 10
```

This takes your variable, `self.score` and adds 10 to the current value of it. The shorthand for this is as follows:

```
self.score += 10
```

Both ways accomplish the same thing, just the second is less to type.